# How do I clear a large persistent collection quickly?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have an entity `Foo` with a `Bars` collection.

This collection is quite big (say, 20,000 elements, and yes, it needs to be loaded entirely, because it's displayed in a TreeView), and the elements are generated automatically based on some parameters of the `Foo` that the user can change, using a WPF MVVM application (all processing occurs in the client)

After he is satisfied with the results, he hits save, and `DbContext.SaveChanges()` is called.

Generating `Bars` implies clearing the collection, then doing a bunch of calculations and adding the new elements. When this is a new, non-persistent `Foo`, it's no problem because I can just call `foo.Bars.Clear()`

The problem is, doing that with already persistent entities causes EF to set `bar.Foo = null` in all the elements, instead of deleting them.

My workaround goes like this:

```
void Regenerate()
{    
    if (fooIsPersistent)
    {
        foreach (var bar in foo.Bars.ToList())
            context.Entry(bar).State = EntityState.Detached;
        deleteOnSave = true;
    }
    else
        foo.Bars.Clear();
    AddTheNewCalculatedElements()
}

void Save()
{
    if (deleteOnSave)
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete Bar where Foo = @Id", param);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem with this solution is that it doesn't scale. Calling                     `Entry(bar).State = EntityState.Detached` when there are many entities loaded is even slower than just calling `context.Set<Bar>().Remove(bar)` and letting EF do the deletes one by one, so it defeats the purpose of the workaround.

So, my question is: **Is there any efficient way to make EF believe the collection is actually empty?**

**Or should I do it in a completely different way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was easier than I thought.

I replaced this line:

```
context.Entry(bar).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

with this one (which I thought was more or less equivalent):

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.Detach(bar);
```

And it now completes in a reasonable time.